# within the for loop, i receive index out of range error

Tags: python, list, range, iteration

When iterating over the list of `x`, I am receiving an error message that **index out of range**. What should be modified in the code? c value multiplies by 1 twice and then goes to the previous value.

```
 for i in range(len(x)):

    if len(x) == 1:
        a.append(x[i] - w)
        c.append((1 + x[i] - a[i])*1)
        d.append((1+x[i])*1)
        if d[i] > max(c[:]):
            f.append(B+a[i])
        else:
            f.append(B)
    else:
        a.append(x[i] - w)
        c.append((1 + x[i] - a[i])*c(i-1))
        d.append((1+x[i])*c(i-1))
        if d[i] > max(c[:-1]):
            f.append(B+a[i])
        else:
            f.append(B)
```

Comment: please provide the stack trace

Comment: You need to provide some info on the variables you are using. You have indexed multiple variables here like - `x`,`a`. The error could be from either of these.

Comment: x is a list of values from another function, a is updated within the loop

Comment: `w`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `f` are accessed here, but we don't see their instantiation and are given no assumptions that can be made about the values.  It looks like `w` is a constant and the rest are lists.  Are the other lists guaranteed to have the same length as `x`?  I would test this first.

Comment: x is a distribution of the random numbers, I initialize empty lists after the loop  for i in range(len(x)):
 a=[]
 c=[]
 d=[] 
 f=[]      
list a updates fine, however c and d not
        if len(x) == 1:

Comment: def form(x,w,B)

for i in range(len(x)):
 a=[]
 c=[]
 d=[] 
 f=[]      

        if len(x) == 1:
            a.append(x[i] - w)
            c.append((1 + x[i] - a[i])*1)
            d.append((1+x[i])*1)
            if d[i] > max(c[:]):
                f.append(B+a[i])
            else:
                f.append(B)
        else:
            a.append(x[i] - w)
            c.append((1 + x[i] - a[i])*c(i-1))
            d.append((1+x[i])*c(i-1))
            if d[i] > max(c[:-1]):
                f.append(B+a[i])
            else:
                f.append(B)

 return f

Comment: the loop is within the formula

Answer (score 1):

if len(x) >1

```
c[i-1] # on i=0 it will access c[-1] and if len(c)<1 then it can raise index error
```

plus  if c is a list change `c(i-1)` to `c[i-1]`

Comment: on a first iteration I want to access c value as 1, and on the second c-1, which would be updated from the formula, but it looks like I'm accessing 1 again

Comment: Then write a condition with i==0

Comment: Are you sure error is within this function check line number in the message. Beginning with empty lists (except x) this runs fine after adding i==0 condition.

Comment: yes, it gives error for the second part where else: c.append((1 + x[i] - a[i])*c[i-1])

Comment: a need to be updated with x[i], and then used in c calculation, so the len(xs) should be 1 to calculate a value

Comment: why should len be 1 to calculate a value. replace condition with i==0.

Comment: to get latest x[i]

Answer (score 0):

You have error with

```
    c.append((1 + x[i] - a[i])*c[i-1])
```

if list c is empty and len(x) > 1, you will get index error while accessing c[i-1] i.e. c[-1] because that is not exist.